# Return the unique character elements that are mixed with numeric ones in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, character, tidyverse

Suppose I have a data.frame that consists of mainly numeric values but also mixed with some character elements.

Is there a way to extract the *unique* character elements throughout the data.frame?

A toy example along with the desired output is shown below?

```
   DF <- data.frame(x = c(1:3, "*", "."), y = c("--", 4:6, "="), z = 1:5, w = rep("a", 5))

   desired_output <- c("*", ".", "--", "=")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract all the values which has only punctuations in it from `DF` using `grep` :

```
unique(grep('^[[:punct:]]+$', as.character(unlist(DF)), value = TRUE))
#[1] "*"  "."  "--" "="
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, do you possibly know the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709786/concept-mapping-in-r-shiny-app-file-upload-issue)?

Comment: Hi..unfortunately no, I am not aware how to solve that.

Comment: I did not test it so I don't know.

Comment: Would you please just try to see if replicate the same error or not? That would be very helpful.